Updating many-to-many relationships in EF Core
Using Entity Framework Core, I've got a couple of Models with a many-to-many relationship - a number of People, each of which has a number of Skills - and I'm having trouble working out the best way to tell Entity Framework to create new links between these objects.
I'm having to use separate Database Contexts for retrieving and saving the data, which seems to make this trickier. For example, this is inside of an API, where the client would GET a Person object and a collection of all available Skills objects, then add or remove Skills to/from the Person, and pass it back to the API with a PUT.
Naturally the real-world case is more complex, but this shows problem in its simplest form. The code below demonstrates the problem end-to-end.
What's the best way to go about doing this? Is there a better way that I could set up the Models themselves to support this kind of operation? I've tried using various combinations of Add or Attach on the Models before calling SaveChanges, but I can't find a way to get EF into the correct state to add or remove the required links.
I imagine this is obvious to an EF veteran, but I'm pretty new to the framework, and I'm unable to locate an answer to this specific question in any of the documentation.
The below code forms a runnable example of what I mean, pasted into a C# console app with a reference to EF Core and a SQL Server available to test.
The Model objects are defined like this: -
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; } = [];
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons { get; } = [];
}

And I've set up a standard database context to go with them: -
public class CatalogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=EFTest;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=true;");
    }
}

The code below sets up the test data, and writes it to the DB: a single Person, two Skills, and a link from the Person to one of the Skills.
// Create initial test data
using (CatalogContext context = new CatalogContext())
{
    Person newPerson = new Person { Name = "Robert Smith" };
    Skill newSkill1 = new Skill { Name = "Singing" };
    Skill newSkill2 = new Skill { Name = "Hairstyle" };

    context.Skills.Add(newSkill1);
    context.Skills.Add(newSkill2);
    newPerson.Skills.Add(newSkill1);
    context.Persons.Add(newPerson);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
Console.WriteLine("Written test data");

Finally, the code below reads these objects back from the DB, then (in a different EF Context, to simulate a different call to an API) it adds a second Skill to the Person and tries to write that state back to the DB.
// Retrieve data - e.g. from GET method
Person person;
List<Skill> skills = [];
using (CatalogContext context = new CatalogContext())
{
    person = context.Persons.Where(p => p.Name == "Robert Smith")
                            .Include(p => p.Skills)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
    skills = context.Skills.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"Person '{person.Name}' has skills '{string.Join(",", person.Skills.Select(x => x.Name))}'");
    Console.WriteLine($"List of all available skills: {string.Join(", ", skills.Select(x => x.Name))}'");
}

// Amend data - e.g. from PUT method
person.Name = "Bob Smith";
person.Skills.Add(skills[1]);
using (CatalogContext context = new CatalogContext())
{
    context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
    foreach (Skill skill in person.Skills)
    {
        skill.Persons.Add(person);
        //context.Entry(skill).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}

// Retrieve data again to check results
using (CatalogContext context = new CatalogContext())
{
    Person personFinal = context.Persons.Where(p => p.Name == "Bob Smith")
                                .Include(p => p.Skills)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine($"Person '{personFinal.Name}' has skills '{string.Join(",", personFinal.Skills.Select(x => x.Name))}'");
}

That's the point at which I'd like the Person to be linked to two Skills, i.e. the EF-generated link table should contain two entries. But that doesn't happen, of course. The change to the name is saved correctly, but there's still just the one link. So I'd like find out what the "most correct" way is to tell EF to accomplish what I'm after.
